# Laravel encrypt string not behaving as expected

Tags: php, laravel, encryption

I have the following code:

```
$user = User::where('UserID', 14)->first();
$encrypted=Crypt::encryptString('MySecretPassword');
$user->smtp_password=$encrypted;
$user->save();

//This outputs the original password MySecretPassword.
dd($user->smtp_password);
//This gives payload is invalid error
$passw=Crypt::decryptString($user->smtp_password);
```

The original encryption(Crypt::encryptString) saves the MySecretPassword as a long encrypted string in the Mysql database. Database datatype type is longtext. When I output the value without doing the decrypt it gives me the original password form not the encrypted string (see code above). Why am I not seeing the the encrypted string from the database ? I havent performed any decryption.

User Model:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Auth;
use Crypt;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    
    
protected $primaryKey = 'UserID';
public $timestamps = false;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password','smtp_password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 
        'remember_token', 
        'driver', 
        'host', 
        'port', 
        'encryption',
        'username',
        'smtp_password'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
    
    
    
    public function getSmtpPasswordAttribute($value)
    {
        return Crypt::decryptString($value);
    }

    
    
public function scopeConfiguredEmail($query) {
$user = Auth::user();
return $query->where('UserID', $user->UserID);
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out `$user->save();`. If that fixes it, that method is changing it. If that doesn't, then inspect `$encrypted` to see if it really is encrypted.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Please can you also show the code for your `User` model.

Comment: User Model added

Comment: Here is your issue `getSmtpPasswordAttribute`. When you get the `$user->smtp_password` back out, it's already decrypting it for you. It will be encrypted in the database.

Comment: Why would it decrypt it for me if I dont call the getSmtpPasswordAttribute function ?

Comment: [Laravel does it for you automatically](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) when you create an accessor.

Comment: Thanks aynber that is the reason.

Comment: I am facing the same issue also I don't have an accessor as well I am using laravel 9.
and issue is coming after upgrade.

Comment: here is my code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74808560/laravel-cryptencryptstring-automatically-get-decrypted-while-saving-in-db