# laravel Crypt::encryptString automatically get decrypted while saving in db

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I am having JSON field in my database where I store the username and password (encrypted).
but after upgrading to Laravel 9 my password is getting stored automatically in decrypted form.

When I print decrypted password it's working properly but in db its getting stored as the original password.

Below is my code.

```
class EmailConfiguration extends BaseModel
{
    protected $table = 'email_configurations';
    protected $guarded = [];
    protected $json = ['configuration'];

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        $jsonToString = function ($model) {
            // Convert all json attributes to string before saving
            foreach ($model->json as $attribute) {
                $model->$attribute = json_encode($model->$attribute);
            }
        };

        $stringToJson = function ($model) {
            // Convert back all json attributes from strings
            foreach ($model->json as $attribute) {
                $data = json_decode($model->$attribute, true);
                $data = $data ?: [];

                // Use fluent interface
                $model->$attribute = new Fluent($data);
            }
        };

        static::saving($jsonToString);
        static::saved($stringToJson);
        static::loaded($stringToJson);
    }


}
```

My repository code to save email configuration.

```
class EmailConfigurationRepository
{
    

    public function save($data)
    {        
        $config= [ 'username'=> $data['user_name'],'password' => Crypt::encryptString($data['password'])];
        $configuration = new EmailConfiguration();
        $configuration->user_id = $data['user_id'];
        $configuration->configuration = $config;
        $configuration->save();

        return $configuration->refresh();
    }

   
}

<?php

namespace App\Support;

use Countable;
use Illuminate\Support\Fluent as FluentBase;
use Iterator;

// We could have simple implemented IteratorAggregate and return an ArrayIterator
// object here. But I want the Fluent access to continue for sub arrays.
// Thus, we are implementing Iterator interface

class Fluent extends FluentBase implements Iterator, Countable
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function get($key, $default = null)
    {
        $value = parent::get($key, $default);

        // If the value is an array, wrap it in a Fluent.
        // Useful for accesses like $a->b->c->d
        return is_array($value) && ! empty($value) ? new self($value) : $value;
    }

    public function rewind()
    {
        return reset($this->attributes);
    }

    public function current()
    {
        return current($this->attributes);
    }

    public function key()
    {
        return key($this->attributes);
    }

    public function next()
    {
        return next($this->attributes);
    }

    public function valid()
    {
        return key($this->attributes) !== null;
    }

    /**
     * Count the number of items in the attributes.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count()
    {
        return count($this->attributes);
    }

    public function merge($data)
    {
        $data = is_fluent($data) ? $data->toArray() : $data;

        return new Fluent(array_merge($this->toArray(), $data));
    }

    public function isEmpty()
    {
        return empty($this->attributes);
    }

    public function isNotEmpty()
    {
        return ! $this->isEmpty();
    }
}
```

**When I print output after saving it's working properly it's returning the password encrypted form but still in db it's getting stored as unencrypted.**

**So assume I enter a username: testing and password: demo123**

In db its getting stored as **demo123**  but when I print before saving model object its showing me in encrypted form.

Comment: At no part of the shared code do you either encrypt or decrypt the password.

Comment: Btw when i remove Fluent class its working so there is something wrong there for sure @apokryfos

Comment: Password should be hashed, not encrypted! Passwords are personal and you should  never be able to decrypt the password.

Comment: @GertB. Dont worry this is not application password this is the password of other app which we needed to call API as that app don't have API token

Comment: I would change your question and example code. `When I print decrypted password it's working properly but in db its getting stored as the original password.`, I would go with: 1) when I print `dd(some variable)`, it shows the ... something. With texts like "it's working properly" or "it's not working", that's difficult to debug. Show where you are throwing in your debug steps

Comment: @UnderDog in EmailConfigurationRepository when I print $config variable before saving it's showing the proper output I mean the encrypted password but in db, it's storing the same password without encryption.

So assume if I entered the password 'test1234' then in DB it is stored as 'test1234' but when I print the output before saving it shows in encrypted form.